# Using Spring WebClient in standalone application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a standalone spring-boot application and want to use Spring's `WebClient` to make requests. But somehow, the `WebClient` is not making the requests. I am able to make requests using `RestTemaplate` though.  Am i missing something, or `WebClient` cannot be used in standalone projects?

```
@Test
public void test() {
        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        // Able to make requests in standalone spring boot project using RestTemplate
        restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/user", User.class)
                    .getBody();

        // NOT Able to make requests in standalone spring boot project using WebClient
        WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/user")
                 .get()
                 .retrieve()
                 .bodyToMono(User.class);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "But somehow, the WebClient is not making the requests" Please [edit] your question to describe exactly what happens when you run your code. Include any error messages or exceptions that you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong... should be something like that:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");
Mono<String> result = webClient.get()
   .retrieve()
   .bodyToMono(String.class);
String response = result.block();
System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: If you need WebClient only for tests it is better to use WebTestClient. There are no advantages in using WebClient against RestTemplate if you call block() method.